# How to filter products by category in custom loop

Tags: filters

```
<form method="GET" class="filter-form">
    <label>Select Category</label>
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'orderby' => 'name'));
    if ($terms) :
        echo '<select name="product-category">';
        foreach ($terms as $term) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // slug of the category as the value of an option
            $url = home_url('product-category') . '/' . $term->slug;
            echo $url;
        //    wp_redirect( $url );
        var_dump($url);
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
    ?>
    <button type="submit">Apply filter</button>
</form>

<div class="featured-courses-container containerr" id="featured-courses-container">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => 1
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="featured-home-link">
                <div class="featured-courses-inner">
                    <p class="card-price color-white">
                        <?php
                        $price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_price', true);
                        echo wc_price($price);
                        ?>
                    </p>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>" alt="featured-courses-img" class="featured-courses-img">
                    <h5 class="color-black featured-card-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <p class="color-black"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="card-extra">
                        <?php
                        $additional_info = get_field('additional_info');
                        if ($additional_info) : ?>
                            <div class="card-extra-inner">
                                <img src="<?php echo content_url(); ?>/uploads/2023/06/image_2023_06_24T07_32_01_588Z.png" alt="" class="featured-courses-img">
                                <p class="color-gray"><?php echo $additional_info['number_of_classes']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="card-extra-inner">
                                <img src="<?php echo content_url(); ?>/uploads/2023/06/image_2023_06_24T07_32_17_171Z.png" alt="" class="featured-courses-img">
                                <p class="color-gray"><?php echo $additional_info['total_time_duration']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-extra-inner">
                                <img src="<?php echo content_url(); ?>/uploads/2023/06/image_2023_06_24T07_32_38_710Z.png" alt="" class="featured-courses-img">
                                <p class="color-gray"><?php echo $additional_info['star_rating']; ?></p>
                            </div> -->
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __('No products found');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
<button class="byvex-btn byvex-center" id="load-more">More Courses
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/Spin.gif" alt="" class="" id="loader">
</button>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `$term->term_id` instead of slug as the option value.
2. Check if the `$_GET['product-category']` exists, then append it to the `$args` array.

   ```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => 1
    );  

    if ( isset($_GET['product-category']) && !empty($_GET['product-category']) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms' => $_GET['product-category'],
            ),
        );
    }

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   ```